# JFrame in GUI class not updating

Tags: swing, jframe

I am very new to JAVA, and am attempting to write a `pharmacokinetics` calculation program for my students to use.

The program reads a database of plasma concentration vs time values and calculates a number of pharmacokinetic parameters and outputs these into a number of frames, as well as drawing linear and exponential curves which are also output into frames.

I wrote the program initially as a console based, to make sure everything worked as required, before moving to GUI. Now comes the difficult steps of GUI building. I realize my console code will change considerably, I'm looking forward to the learning curve.

I am now attempting to output results via a separate 'GUI' class, and so pass frames between classes before output. I have tried to pass a frame from my 'GUI' class to my other class, without success.

In my attempt to learn GUI, and the class structure of JAVA, I have two classes.

1. A `ProjectChart` Class, that contains all the calculation and graphing methods.
2. A `ProjectChartGUI` class, which will eventually be used to output all data.

`ProjectChartGUI` currently defines a number of `InternalFrames`. I have been trying to pass one such `internalframe` to a function in `ProjectChart`, `OutputInputData()`. This constructs a table of data, read by a separate function, and will output this table into a frame for user validation.

I am trying to pass a `JInternalFrame` from `ProjectChartGUI` to `OutputInputData()`.

Initially I passed the JInternalFrame using a `.getFrame()` function using `OutputInputData (JInternalFrame frame)`.

I also tried to pass a ProjectchartGUI object. `OutputInputData (ProjectChartGUI tProjectChartGUI)`. This also did not work.

In both cases, the program runs, all calculations are performed successfully, however the frame which opens via ProjectChartGUI is empty.

Here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException{

   ProjectChartGUI tGUI = new ProjectChartGUI();

   /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            ActionPharmacokinetics(tGUI);
            tGUI.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

   }
```

Here is a snippet of the function ActionPharmacokinetics():

```
public static void ActionPharmacokinetics(ProjectChartGUI tGUI){
   DetermineUserInput();

    if(CHECK == IVBOLUS_TRUE)
    {
        // Read database to access main information
        Access_IVBOLUS_DatabaseList();

        // Read database again to allow user to select desired entry for calculation
        Access_IVBOLUS_Database();

        // Output CP and T values to a new window for confirmation
        OutputInputData(tGUI);

        //Diplay Linear chart of Data
        Display_IVBOLUS_LinearGraph();

        // Display exponential chart of Data
        Display_IVBOLUS_ExponentialGraph();

        // Calculate pharmacokinetic parameters
        Calculate_IVBOLUS_PharmacokineticParameters();

        // Output pharmacokinetic paramaters
        OutputPharmacokineticParamaters();

    }}
```

Here is outputInputData(): `Cp, lnCp and T` are declared variables in ProjectChart. `Numberofpoints` is the `numberofdata` points read from the database.

```
static public void OutputInputData(ProjectChartGUI tGUI){

    //create table objects
    String[] ColumnNames = new String[]{"Data Point", "CP"+Units_CP,"ln CP","Time"+Units_T};
    double SetDecimalPoint = 0.0;
    Object[][] Data = new Object[NumberofPoints][4];
    for (int k=0;k<NumberofPoints;k++)
    {
        Data[k][0] = k+1;//index
        Data[k][1] = Cp[k];//plasma

        SetDecimalPoint = lnCp[k];//log plasma
        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(SetDecimalPoint);
        bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); // rounds ln cp to 2 decimal places for output
        Data[k][2] = bd;

        Data[k][3] = T[k];//time
    }

   //create table
   JTable jtable = new JTable(Data, ColumnNames);

   //Create frame
   //JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Input Data");
   //jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //add table to frame
    tGUI.getframe().add(new JScrollPane(jtable));
    tGUI.getframe().pack(); //auto size
    tGUI.getframe().setVisible(true);

   }
```

`.getframe()` returns an internal frame from `ProjectChartGUI`

```
public javax.swing.JInternalFrame getframe(){
return jInternalFrame1;
}
```

I used Netbeans GUI builder to define a frame, with an internal frame

```
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
```

All other code in ProjectChartGUI was autogenerated by Netbeans.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Very solid question but please read `HowToAsk` section of our community.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 3) @xenteros *"Very solid question.."* What question? OP: I did a search through that words/code for any instance of `?` and there was none. Please add a `?` to the end of questions, or if you forgot to ask one, please form a specific question (could be as general as 'How to fix the problem?') & add it as an [edit to the post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13114044).

Comment: I did a huge edit, but someone else has done one before so I can't post it.

Comment: revalidate() and validate() . Try those swing methods